# Why does ping -f act like this?

Tags: ping

```
ping -f -s 65500 ip_address
```

I'm using this command to try a sample DoS attack.

Generally cursor is progressing but sometimes cursor is blinking like this:

[image]

Generally:

[image]

What is the meaning of this?

Is there any better command than this one? Maybe a command specialized for HTTP?

```
ping -f -s 65500 ip_address
```

Comment: Close voters: This question is about using the ping command in ubuntu and is not off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1.** from `man ping`:

```
   -f     Flood  ping.  For  every  ECHO_REQUEST  sent  a  period  ``.'' is printed, while for ever ECHO_REPLY
          received a backspace is printed.  This provides a rapid  display  of  how  many  packets  are  being
          dropped.   If  interval  is  not given, it sets interval to zero and outputs packets as fast as they
          come back or one hundred times per second, whichever is more.  Only  the  super-user  may  use  this
          option with zero interval.
```

So, your first screenshot says that for every packet sent a reply from the server has been received.

Your second screenshot says that a few packets have been lost since you started the command.

**2.** There are a few tools for benchmarking/load-testing HTTP servers, for example [ab](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab)

**3.** Performing Denial of Service attacks on somebody else's servers is illegal in many jurisdictions. I'm sure you're talking about stress-testing your own web servers and I suggest you to edit your question to reflect that. Most Linux tools for benchmarking and stress-testing will work in Ubuntu, there's no need for Ubuntu-specific documentation.

Comment: I dont think the OP is using the attacks for pen testing / benchmarks , nowhere in his question did he state anything about pentesting. May i suggest you remove as it is no help to anyone teaching someone how to attack a network?

Comment: @TrevorClarke: The domain name on the first screenshot is clearly  OP's own website, so I'd give the OP benefit of the doubt and assume he is stress-testing his own website. Also note that my answer explains the use of stock-standard Linux tools, not that I'm instructing him how to set up a network of zombie machines to perform a real DDoS attack...

Comment: @Sergey Not the second one :)